# Move two CCSprites in Cocos2d/spritebuilder

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I have two sprites in my scene that I'd like to move in different directions. I tried the following method from searching around but I can't get anything to work. This is the best I have to date.
If anyone can lend a hand that would be great.

```
-(void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
if(CGRectContainsPoint([redLeash boundingBox], touchLocation))
{
redLeash.position = touchLocation;
}
else if
(CGRectContainsPoint([blueLeash boundingBox], touchLocation))
{
blueLeash.position = touchLocation;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. I typed it up here so there might be some syntax errors but it should work.

```
-(void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint([redLeash boundingBox], touchLocaiton))
    {
       [redLeash setPosition:touchlocation];
    }
    else if (CGRectContainsPoint([blueLeash boundingBox], touchLocation))
    {
      [blueLeash setPosition:touchLocation];
    }
  }
```